# Remapping CapsLock to Control when using a PS2-to-USB adapter?

Tags: usb, keyboard-layout

#### The setup

I'm trying to remap the <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> key to be <kbd>Control</kbd> when using my Model M keyboard (with trackpoint) with a PS2-to-USB adaptor.

#### The problem

If the now-remapped control key stays pressed for more than half a second or so, it stops modifying subsequent characters. That is, if I press <kbd>control</kbd>, press and release <kbd>x</kbd>, wait half a second, press and release <kbd>c</kbd>, I get <kbd>control</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>c</kbd> instead of <kbd>control</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>control</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd>. You can imagine that this can be a problem for an emacs and bash user!

This problem does *not* manifest itself with regular USB keyboards, with built-in laptop keyboards, in Windows, or if I don't remap the capslock to control.

I've used **System Settings > Input Devices > Keyboard** in Kubuntu to do the remapping, and I've also done straight xmodmap. Same behavior. Since setkeycodes has no effect on usb keyboards, I can't use that.

#### Workarounds I am not interested in:

- Use a Unicomp USB keyboard. While the buckling-spring mechanism is identical to IBM/Lexmark's, the quality of the trackpoint is inferior, making it practically unusable. The mouse keys are also unreliable. Pity, because that would have been the right solution. Plus they've changed the form factor to something ugly.
- Use a non-buckling spring keyboard. Obviously not an option!
- Not remap the keys. Against my religion.
- Drop Linux and use Windows (where the problem does not exist). Also against my religion.
- Drop Linux and use OSX. OSX has the same problem, plus it's against my religion.

The solution I *am* considering is building one of [these](https://github.com/tmk/tmk_keyboard) and doing the remapping that way, but it's a bit extreme. I'd rather do it in software.

Comment: You are unclear to what you want. Your title says you want to remap, but then you say you don't want to remap. I can help you, if it involves remapping ctrl to capslock.

Comment: Where did I say don't want to remap?

Comment: "Not remap the keys. Against my religion."

Comment: Please read my posting carefully. That's something I am *not* interested in!

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be a hardware problem. At some point noticed that a different PS2-USB adaptor did not have that problem, switched to that brand, and the problem solved itself.

The device that works well is made (repackaged, really) by Belkin, and identifies itself as

```
ID 0d3d:0001 Tangtop Technology Co., Ltd HID Keyboard
```

(Yes, it only says "keyboard", but `lsusb -v` shows that it has both a keyboard and a mouse descriptor, obviously).

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to solve the problem by finding out the respective identities of the PS/2 -> USB adapter and the keyboard.

Try the command

```
lsusb
```

For me it showed, among other things, that there is a

```
Bus 001 Device 018: ID 04d9:1400 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. PS/2 keyboard + mouse controller
```

The first part of the USB identity code (04d9) identifies the manufacturer, and the second the product.

Now you can use that information to discover the identities of devices connected to that adapter by typing

```
xinput list --long | grep 04d9
```

What I got was

```
↳ HID 04d9:1400                             id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]

↳ HID 04d9:1400                             id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

I have no keyboard attached to the adapter, but there is my old trackball mouse, Logitech TrackMan Marble FX.

So I wanted to know more about the device identified above as `id=9`, and I used `xinput` command to get what I wanted:

```
xinput list-props 9
```

The first line of the listing was

```
Device 'HID 04d9:1400':
```

The listing also shows the properties of the device, and I used those to build commands needed for modifying those properties. What I ended with was two commands:

```
xinput set-int-prop "pointer:HID 04d9:1400" "Evdev Wheel Emulation Button" 8 3
xinput set-int-prop "pointer:HID 04d9:1400" "Evdev Wheel Emulation" 8 1
```

The first line turns Button 3 of the TrackMan mouse into a Wheel emulation button. (Button 4 a.k.a. "8" does not seem to work at all). "Pointer" in the commands refers to the mouse and prevents confusing things with "keyboard" that could be attached to the same adapter (not in my system).

Similarly you could perhaps modify the properties of your keyboard with commands like

```
xinput set-int-prop "keyboard:HID (keyboard usb-identifier) (property to be set)
```

etc with other individual properties